# Varnish crash in overloads

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

Im using varnish v 4.1.1, in our system after a while varnish suddenly crush and iowait raise a lot and we should restart varnish for fixing it.
this is journalctl resault after crushing varnish:
question2:
I decided to installing new version of varnish,
Which version is the best?
varnish_6.3.1-1xenial_amd64.deb OR
varnish_6.0.5-1xenial_amd64.deb
Thanks for Ur answer

```
-- Logs begin at Tue ********************************** --

Nov 19 17:29:58 varnish-06 systemd[1]: Started Varnish HTTP accelerator.
Nov 19 17:29:59 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Debug: Platform: Linux,4.4.0-154-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Nov 19 17:29:59 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Platform: Linux,4.4.0-154-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Nov 19 17:29:59 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Debug: Child (9342) Started
Nov 19 17:29:59 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Child (9342) Started
Nov 19 17:29:59 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Info: Child (9342) said Child starts
Nov 19 17:29:59 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Child (9342) said Child starts
Nov 19 17:30:10 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Error: Manager got SIGINT
Nov 19 17:30:10 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Debug: Stopping Child
Nov 19 17:30:10 varnish-06 systemd[1]: Stopping Varnish HTTP accelerator...
Nov 19 17:30:10 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Manager got SIGINT
Nov 19 17:30:10 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Stopping Child
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Error: Child (9342) died signal=15
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 varnishd[9205]: Debug: Child cleanup complete
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 systemd[1]: Stopped Varnish HTTP accelerator.
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 systemd[1]: Started Varnish HTTP accelerator.
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 varnishd[10479]: Debug: Platform: Linux,4.4.0-154-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 varnishd/varnish[10479]: Platform: Linux,4.4.0-154-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 varnishd[10479]: Debug: Child (10513) Started
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 varnishd/varnish[10479]: Child (10513) Started
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 varnishd[10479]: Info: Child (10513) said Child starts
Nov 19 17:30:11 varnish-06 varnishd/varnish[10479]: Child (10513) said Child starts
Nov 20 17:22:11 varnish-06 systemd[1]: Stopping Varnish HTTP accelerator...
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd[10479]: Error: Child (10513) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd/varnish[10479]: Child (10513) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd[10479]: Error: Child (10513) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd[10479]: Error: Manager got SIGINT
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd/varnish[10479]: Child (10513) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd[10479]: Debug: Stopping Child
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd/varnish[10479]: Manager got SIGINT
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd/varnish[10479]: Stopping Child
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd[10479]: Error: Child (10513) died signal=15
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd/varnish[10479]: Child (10513) died signal=15
Nov 20 17:22:18 varnish-06 varnishd[10479]: Debug: Child cleanup complete
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for OOM in dmesg if you find any then your system is Out Of Memory, reason why Varnish is being killed.

Also free `--human gives` you a good overview of available memory.